# Display Current Font While Loading Custom Fonts

Tags: fonts, fabricjs

I'm following the [Loading custom fonts page](http://fabricjs.com/loadfonts) to incorporate a few Google Fonts into my application. Currently I'm able to change fonts, but I'd like to have the dropdown read the currently selected object's font, so that if I decide to change the second text, I'm not forced to deselect the original text's font (if that makes sense, [please check out this fiddle to see what I mean](http://jsfiddle.net/code4ever/an6rmy29/1/)). In other words, it displays the default and then the last used font.

Here's what I'm working with (same as the JSFiddle):

```js
/* 

When working with custom fonts on a fabric canvas, it is recommended to
use a font preloader. Not doing so is likely to cause texts that are
imported onto the canvas to be rendered with a wrong (default) font. It
can also cause you to see a FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text) right after
changing the font of a text. The reason behind this is that the browser 
will only load a font after it is used in the DOM. Preloading fonts 
prevents this from happening. In this example we are using Font Face
Observer (https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) to preload 
Google Fonts, using the following steps:

- Add the custom fonts using @import in your CSS
- Make an array containing the names of all the custom fonts
- Load all the custom fonts using a promise
- When the promise is fulfilled, initialize the fabric canvas

*/

// Define an array with all fonts
var fonts = ["Pacifico", "VT323", "Quicksand", "Inconsolata"];

// Load all fonts using Font Face Observer
Promise.all(
  fonts.map(font => new FontFaceObserver(font).load())
).then(function() {
  
  // When all fonts are loaded, initialize the fabric canvas
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  
  // Populate the fontFamily select
  var select = document.getElementById("font-family");
  fonts.forEach(function(font) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = font;
    option.value = font;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });
  
  // Add a Textbox using a custom font
  var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet', { 
  left: 200,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
   fontSize: 20
 });
  canvas.add(textbox).setActiveObject(textbox);
 
   // Add a Textbox using a custom font
  var textbox2 = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet', { 
  left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
   fontSize: 20
 });
  canvas.add(textbox2);
  
  // Apply selected font on change
  document.getElementById('font-family').onchange = function() {
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", this.value);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  };
  
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|VT323|Quicksand|Inconsolata');

canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/master/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
<br />Font-family: <select id="font-family"></select>
```

How might I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the dropdown value from active object. You can get that from `selection:created` and `selection:updated` event.

```js
/* 

When working with custom fonts on a fabric canvas, it is recommended to
use a font preloader. Not doing so is likely to cause texts that are
imported onto the canvas to be rendered with a wrong (default) font. It
can also cause you to see a FOUT (Flash of Unstyled Text) right after
changing the font of a text. The reason behind this is that the browser 
will only load a font after it is used in the DOM. Preloading fonts 
prevents this from happening. In this example we are using Font Face
Observer (https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver) to preload 
Google Fonts, using the following steps:

- Add the custom fonts using @import in your CSS
- Make an array containing the names of all the custom fonts
- Load all the custom fonts using a promise
- When the promise is fulfilled, initialize the fabric canvas

*/
// Define an array with all fonts
var fonts = ["Pacifico", "VT323", "Quicksand", "Inconsolata"];

// Load all fonts using Font Face Observer
Promise.all(
  fonts.map(font => new FontFaceObserver(font).load())
).then(function() {

  // When all fonts are loaded, initialize the fabric canvas
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

  // Populate the fontFamily select
  var select = document.getElementById("font-family");
  fonts.forEach(function(font) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.innerHTML = font;
    option.value = font;
    select.appendChild(option);
  });

  // Add a Textbox using a custom font
  var textbox = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet', {
    left: 200,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
    fontSize: 20
  });
  canvas.add(textbox).setActiveObject(textbox);

  // Add a Textbox using a custom font
  var textbox2 = new fabric.Textbox('Lorum ipsum dolor sit amet', {
    left: 50,
    top: 50,
    width: 150,
    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
    fontSize: 20
  });
  canvas.add(textbox2);

  // Apply selected font on change
  var fontDropDown = document.getElementById('font-family');
  fontDropDown.onchange = function() {
    canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontFamily", this.value);
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  };
  canvas.on('selection:created', function(options) {
    if (options.target.type == 'textbox') {
      fontDropDown.value = options.target.fontFamily;
    }
  });
  canvas.on('selection:updated', function(options) {
    if (options.target.type == 'textbox') {
      fontDropDown.value = options.target.fontFamily;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico|VT323|Quicksand|Inconsolata');

canvas {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver/master/fontfaceobserver.js"></script>
Font-family: <select id="font-family"></select><br />
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="300"></canvas>
```